# Get term type during evaluation using Hindley-Milner type system

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-checking, type-inference

I've implemented a lambda calculus evaluator and use the Hindley-Milner algorithm to infer terms types and ensure type correctness without the user having to explicitly annotate types.

But now I'd like to add a `typeof` operator that given a term, it returns the type of the term. So far, what I do is keep a hash map of terms to types that is populated during type checking. So if I do `typeof 123`, when the type checker determines the type of `123`, it'll add `123 = Number` to the hash map and look it up when `typeof 123` is evaluated.

The problem with this approach is that if I have this term:

```
let _typeof = \a.(typeof a) in (_typeof 123)
```

Since `\a.(typeof a)` is polymorphic and has type `a -> Type`, the result will be `a` instead of `Number` as I'd expect. If instead I had this:

```
(_typeof.(_typeof 123) \a.(typeof a))
```

Then I'd get the right type `Number` since `\a.(typeof a)` is not polymorphic.

So all I need is a way to handle polymorphism. I'm having a hard time getting my head around it and I wonder if there is a known way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashing of terms to types sounds like a hack to me (or possibly premature optimization and a hell created by stateful programming). During type inference you should tag *every* subterm with its computed type. Then during evaluation `typeof` simply projects the type.

The hell is in the deatils, of course. Here are some initial thoughts about how this would go (I did not actually implement this, but if I did, I would start from [Poly](https://github.com/andrejbauer/plzoo/tree/master/src/poly) in [PLZoo](https://github.com/andrejbauer/plzoo)).

We define the following datatypes:

- a datatype `ty` of polymoprhic types
- a datatype `preterm` of raw terms (the parser gives you these)
- a datatype `term` of tyepchecked terms (type inference converts preterms to these)
- a datatype `value` of values

Maybe like this, using OCaml syntax:

```
(* the result of parsing is a preterm *)
type preterm =
  | PreType
  | PreNumeral of int
  | PreTypeof of preterm
  | PreVar of string
  | PreLet of string * preterm * preterm
  | PreApp of preterm * preterm
  | PreLambda of string * preterm

type ty =
  | Type (* the type of all types *)
  | Number
  | Parameter of int
  | Arrow of ty * ty

(* after type inference every term is tagged with its type *)
type term = term' * ty
and term' =
  | Type
  | Numeral of int
  | Typeof of term
  | Var of int (* using de Bruijn indices *)
  | Let of term * term (* using de Bruijn indices *)
  | App of term * term
  | Lambda of term (* using de Bruijn indices *)

(* a typing context *)
type ctx = ty list

(* a runtime environment *)
type env = value list

(* values are explicitly tagged with their types *)
and value = value' * ty
and value' =
  | ValType of ty
  | ValNumeral of int
  | ValLambda of env * term
```

The parser gives us a `preterm`. Then we define

```
infer : ctx -> preterm -> term
```

and an evaluator

```
eval : env -> term -> value
```

The evaluator now has an easy time evaluating `typeof e` as

```
let rec eval env = function
  ...
  | Typeof e -> 
    let (_, t) = eval env e in
      (ValType t, Type)
  ...
```

Let us work through your example

```
let _typeof = (λ x . typeof x) in _typeof 123
```

First, `infer` would find out that `_typeof` has type `α -> Type`. In the application `_typeof 123` it would try to match (a fresh instance of) `α` against the type `Number` and would succeed with setting `α = Number`. It would then conclude that the type of `_typeof 123` is `Type`.

Second, when `eval` gets to evaluation of `_typeof 123` it actually sees something like

```
(App ((Var 0, Arrow (Parameter 0, Type)), (Numeral 123, Number)), Type)
```

which is an application of bound variable `0` to the numeral `123`, together with typing information: the bound variable `0` has type `Arrow (Parameter 0, Type)` which corresponds to `α -> Type`, the numeral has type `Number`, and the entire expression has type `Type`. The evaluator first evaluates

```
(Var 0, Arrow (Parameter 0, Type))
```

which involves looking up the `0`-th variable in the environment. It gets back a pair `((env', e), Arrow (Parameter 0, Type))` where `(env', e)` is a closure representing `λ x . typeof x`. Then it evaluates the argument and gets `(ValNumeral 123, Number)`. It remains to evaluate `e` applied to `(ValNumeral 123, Number)` which is done the usual way with a recursive call to `eval` in `env'` extended with `(ValNumeral 123, Number)`. Here `e` is going to be something like

```
(Typeof (Var 0, Parameter 0), Type)
```

which corresponds to the expression `typeof x`, except that `x` is replaced by de Bruijn index `0` and is tagged to have "any type". Now we need to pay attention (here is where you have a mistake that gives you `α` instead of `Number`): we first evaluate `(Var 0, Parameter 0)` by looking up the `0`-th elemenent of `(ValNumeral 123, Number) :: env'`, so we get `(ValNumeral 123, Number)`. Now we evaluate `Typeof` by taking the second component, which is `Number`. It would be *wrong* to evaluate `Typeof` by simply returning `Parameter 0`, we actually have to evaluate its argument and then take the type of that). The final value therefore is

```
(Type Number, Type)
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Just to make sure I understand, would this imply replacing type variables with types taken from the environment during evaluation every time polymorphic terms are evaluated, even in places I'm not calling `typeof` so that types are propagated until I eventually call `typeof`?. So for instance `(λa.λb.a 123)`should return a value & type tuple, and the type be `b -> Number` which would be the result of replacing the type `a` with `Number` during evaluation.

Comment: Please do *not* use the same letter for the variable and for its type, that is a great source of errors. So instead of saying that `λ a . a` has type `a → a` you should say that that `λ x . x` has type `α → α`. For instance, you say "replace the type `a` with `Number` during evaluation", but in the expression `λ a . λ  b . a 123` the symbol `a` is *not* a type, it is an argument. And note that you did not use `b` at all.

Comment: I think `λ x . λ y. x 123` should have type `(Number → α) → (β → γ) → α`. Did you mean to write `λ x . x 123`?

Comment: Maybe you think that since we're going to evaluate everything to tuples (value, type) all λ-abstractions will take two arguments? That is wrong. The type annotations are "hidden in the background" (the evaluator "secretly" keeps track of types). The identity function is still written as `λ x . x` and *not* as `λ x . λ a . x`.

Comment: That was really just an example. I meant to say, since `λa.λb.a` has type `α → β → α`, applying this to `123` during evaluation should return the value `λb.123`, which has type `β → Number`,  and this type would need to be constructed during evaluation (in the background as you said) each time the function `λa.λb.a` is called by basically cloning the type of `λb.a` which is `β → α` and replacing every occurrence of `α` (or its de Bruijn index) with `Number` to get `β → Number`.

Comment: Right, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider the approach Haskell uses to solve this problem, which is to say via typeclasses.  A typeclass is a set of functions that can be implemented by many types. When a polymorphic function needs to be able to call such a function on a type that is unknown, it is silently modified to add an extra parameter, the "dictionary" for the type's instance of the type class (which is a structure containing the functions for that type's instance). Then call sites where the actual type is known are silently modified to pass the correct instance, and so on.

Then you just need a type class "Typeable" that is automatically defined for all types and which contains an appropriate "typeOf" for each defined type.

This may not be the *easiest* way of achieving what you want, but it leaves you with extremely useful general mechanism for solving many kinds of polymorphism problems, so it might be the most *useful* way of achieving what you want.

Simplifying the way this works in Haskell slightly (because AIUI Haskell's implementation involves an optimization that is conceptually unnecessary):

The typeclass `Typeable` is translated to a record type containing a function `forall a . a -> Type`.  The function `typeOf` is defined with type `Typeable a => a -> Type` which means that there is an implicit parameter of type `Typeable`.  `typeOf` is defined to simply unwrap the function from the record and call it.

A polymorphic function that calls `typeOf` needs to get a dictionary for its type argument, so any such function is inferred to have type `Typeable a => [whatever the type would have been originally]` for any type variable `a` that it needs to call `typeOf` for.  This also means that there is an implicit argument to this function, too.

A function that calls `typeOf` for a known type has to provide an argument for the implicit arguments.  This is calculated during the type checking phase, and it picks an appropriate predefined instance for the type of the term (which it obviously knows, because it has just type-checked it).

So in your example from the comments, the type checker knows that the term `typeOf` is applied to has type `[Number]` so it picks an instance for that type and adds that as a parameter.

So far, this is just the usual implementation of typeclasses.  The twist here is that the type checker treats `Typeable` as a special case and *generates the instances itself on demand* so there will always be an instance available for any type that exists in the program.

It may also be worth noting that the instance for `[a]` can potentially delegate to the instance for `a` and wrap/otherwise modify the result.  This may reduce the number of instances that are required.

Comment: Any clue of how's that implemented? I see that evaluating `typeOf (if True then [] else [10])` will return the right type `[Integer]` even though the list is empty, so somehow the empty list "knows" is an empty list of integers without having to look into any of its items.

Comment: See also this stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600380/what-is-haskells-data-typeable

Comment: I've added more detail to the answer which will hopefully answer the question in your comment.